# select part from html

Tags: regex, parsing, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I was wondering how I could select something from an (html)string. For example this is a line from an html page:

```
<meta property='og:title' content="blablabla" />
```

Here I want to select `blablabla`.

I'm working in a Windows Phone project with C#.
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex to get the string within double quotes,

```
(?<==\")[^"]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/19)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use JQuery instead of regex?

```
$("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reliable code is

```
   var doc = XDocument.Parse("<meta property='og:title' content='blablabla' />");
   MessageBox.Show(doc.Element("meta").Attribute("content").Value);
```